# Android Studio App does not open (Mapbox)

Tags: android-studio, dictionary, mobile, crash, mapbox

I want to build an app with mapbox where a map is displayed. I used this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTlOaFm6ttU&lc=UgzYC-Y-6pEmrsmmvTl4AaABAg.9F9Fdptkxka9FDwq0btJOL
There are many videos that simply show the same code but it never works. When running the code it says that there is no error and the app on the virtual device opens. But after a second of blank screen it closes immediatly.

Main Activity:

```
package com.example.mapboxedtmdev;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.constants.Style;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MapView mapView;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Mapbox.getInstance(this, "pk.eyJ1Ijoia2VycnlraWxpYW4iLCJhIjoiY2tna3QzMzZnMG1naTMwbmE4ejF0dnFuZiJ9.BXqcjQ4giUcsL1VDzTqPSQ");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mapView=(MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.setStyleUrl(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:mapbox_cameraTargetLat="16"
        app:mapbox_cameraTargetLng="108"
        app:mapbox_cameraZoom="11"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In Android Manifest I added the permissions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mapboxedtmdev">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

In Build.gradle(Module) I added this under dependencies:

```
compile ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.0.2@aar')
            {
                transitive=true
            }
```

In Build.gradle(Project) I added the mavenCentral():

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The Logcat just shows this in red:

```
2020-10-26 11:29:52.571 9436-9436/com.example.mapboxedtmdev E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mapboxedtmdev, PID: 9436
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mapboxedtmdev/com.example.mapboxedtmdev.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: getDataNetworkTypeForSubscriber
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: getDataNetworkTypeForSubscriber
        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2373)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2357)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2340)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2282)
        at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.getNetworkTypeForSubscriber(ITelephony.java:8762)
        at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getNetworkType(TelephonyManager.java:3021)
        at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getNetworkType(TelephonyManager.java:2985)
        at com.mapbox.services.android.telemetry.utils.TelemetryUtils.getCellularNetworkType(TelemetryUtils.java:102)
        at com.mapbox.services.android.telemetry.MapboxTelemetry.pushEvent(MapboxTelemetry.java:482)
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView.onCreate(MapView.java:207)
        at com.example.mapboxedtmdev.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:56)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
2020-10-26 11:29:52.611 9436-9436/com.example.mapboxedtmdev I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9436 SIG: 9
```

I hope anyone can help me because it seems that the app works on every other pc but not at my pc.

Comment: Probably this issue is only for Android 11!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: Take another device. At first, I had a virtual device (Google Pixel 2) but now I took my own smartphone as device.

Comment: so you mean to say that with virtual device MapBox doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

add `implementation "implementation com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-telemetry:6.1.0"`
to dependencies block in build.gradle
this issue is about new policy of android, and will fix later.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).